# how to stream a ruby application logs from /var/log folder of a vm machine to compute engine logging dashboard

Tags: logging, google-compute-engine, monitoring, stackdriver

1. How can I export a ruby application logs from, say /var/log/project/ folder of a VM instance on GCP to the google cloud logging interface? I am using stackdriver and I have already installed the stackdriver gem to the gemfile.
2. While using the stackdriver gem, must the service account associated to this project have logging roles attached to it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/ruby) to setup Stackdriver Logging for Ruby. Once the Stackdriver Logging library for Ruby is enabled, you can use the logger in your application. [Here is link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-logging) for the installation instructions and more information on the google-cloud-logging. You can configure logger to customize the logging behavior (eg: source file).
2. It will require to use the service-account associated to the project. The google-cloud-logging library uses Service Account credentials to connect to Google Cloud Services.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to solving this issues was in locating the stack driver configuration file folder which is located at /etc/google-fluentd and /var/google-fluentd/pos. in these folders lies the configuration files for which logs to be read and sent to google cloud's console and the position of the last read log position. 
All that assuming that you have the right service account credentials and resource roles assigned to those service accounts and additionally defining the scopes in the google compute instance template.